# How to add post processing to UI (UI toolkit, NOT CANVAS) in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, post-processing, urp

I'm working on a Unity game and I want to add chromatic aberration to the interface but have no idea how to do it and can't find anything similar on the Unity docs site.

I don't use Canvas, I use UIDocument.

My project uses Universal RP but I will accept answer for any other render pipeline as long as it explains how to add post processing to the UI visual elements (uxml)

I have tried using several cameras. It's stupid, but it's the only thing I could try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIToolkit uses a screen space overlay, ie. renders after the cameras, although they are considering adding world-space support.

It also doesn't support custom materials or ShaderGraph, although, again, they are considering adding support.

You can see the rendering feature support on [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/UI-system-compare.html).

This means your only option is to render the UIDocument to a texture, and use that texture on a UGUI object or a world space quad. Then you should be able to apply post-processing.
You can specify a render texture in the PanelSettings object.